# Position the number below the barcode, using pyBarcode

Tags: python, django

I'm using `pyBarcode` to generate PNGs and the number below the barcode is getting cut off on the right. How do I nudge it left a few pixels?

[image: the number is getting cut off]

According to [the documentation](http://packages.python.org/pyBarcode/writers/index.html#common-writer-options) I need to do something like this:

```
barcode.writer.BaseWriter(paint_text=my_callback)
```

And define a callback like this:

```
my_callback(xpos, ypos)
```

and:

```
use self.text as text
```

How exactly do I apply all of that to my Django view (below)?

```
def barcode(request):
    import barcode
    from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
    from cStringIO import StringIO

    def mm2px(mm, dpi=300):
        return (mm * dpi) / 25.4

    class MyImageWriter(ImageWriter):
        def calculate_size(self, modules_per_line, number_of_lines, dpi=300):
            width = 2 * self.quiet_zone + modules_per_line * self.module_width
            height = 1.0 + self.module_height * number_of_lines
            if self.text:
                height += (self.font_size + self.text_distance) / 3

            return int(mm2px(width, dpi)), int(mm2px(height, dpi))

    f = BarcodeForm(request.GET)
    if f.is_valid():
        try:
            i = StringIO()
            bc_factory = barcode.get_barcode_class(f.PYBARCODE_TYPE[f.cleaned_data['barcode_type']])
            bc_factory.default_writer_options['quiet_zone'] = 1.0
            bc_factory.default_writer_options['text_distance'] = 1.0
            bc_factory.default_writer_options['module_height'] = 15.0
            bc_factory.default_writer_options['module_width'] = 0.3
            bc_factory.default_writer_options['font_size'] = 46

            bc = bc_factory(f.cleaned_data['text'], writer=MyImageWriter())
            bc.write(i)
            return HttpResponse(i.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')
        except Exception, e:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(str(e))
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Missing text or unsupported barcode type: %s' % f.errors)
```

Comment: You could report it as a bug to the pyBarcode author.

Comment: @Craig I did: https://bitbucket.org/whitie/pybarcode/issue/6/how-to-position-the-text-below-the-barcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: After answering I noticed you've got a factory that's setting the `quiet_zone` to `1.0`. Change that back to `6.5` and I'd imagine it will look fine.

Edit2: I misunderstood the exact problem you were experiencing.

For whatever reason the author of `pyBarcode` is putting the text centered in the middle of the bar code. When the render method calls `_paint_text()` it passes in `xpos/2`, which sets it in the middle of the barcode. I guess this is okay with the default font he's using, but when you increased the font, it no longer fits.

Instead I was able to place it on the left side, by overriding the `_paint_text()` method. In the last line below, the variable `pos` is just a tuple containing an (x,y) coordinate that tells PIL where to draw the text on the bar code. So I've made sure x is lined up with the bar code. If you need it right aligned, you could play around with the `xpos` variable to get it where you need.

Give this a shot:

```
class MyImageWriter(ImageWriter):
    def calculate_size(self, modules_per_line, number_of_lines, dpi=300):
        width = 2 * self.quiet_zone + modules_per_line * self.module_width
        height = 1.0 + self.module_height * number_of_lines
        if self.text:
            height += (self.font_size + self.text_distance) / 3

        return int(mm2px(width, dpi)), int(mm2px(height, dpi))

    def _paint_text(self, xpos, ypos):
        # this should align your font to the left side of the bar code:
        xpos = self.quiet_zone
        pos = (mm2px(xpos, self.dpi), mm2px(ypos, self.dpi))
        font = ImageFont.truetype(FONT, self.font_size)
        self._draw.text(pos, self.text, font=font, fill=self.foreground)
```

Comment: [Screenshot of that.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26816257/barcode_quiet.png) As `quiet_zone` increases, the number below the barcode becomes visible but it's off center. I need this to look like a normal barcode.

Comment: I see. Check above, I've edited my answer -- hopefully it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: I added the _paint_text function but now the barcode doesn't appear at all. I've also tried adding: `import os` and `from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont` and `PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` as well as `FONT = os.path.join(PATH, 'DejaVuSansMono.ttf')` per [this](https://bitbucket.org/whitie/pybarcode/src/1400018306e5/barcode/writer.py) -- but still the barcode doesn't appear. Thoughts?

Comment: Put this pastebin in a file called `bc.py`: http://pastebin.com/TQcMp8PZ .. In the same directory, place the font file -- it works for me. My guess is that the python file your view is sitting in can't access the font file.

Comment: You were right - it couldn't find the font file. Works! Thanks.